# Is there way to lower the lockfileVersion of npm-shrinkwrap to lockfileVersion@1, it automatically makes lockfileversion@2?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, npm-shrinkwrap

[ERROR] - An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error signal: killed. Stderr:npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by removing node_modules and package.json file and then, installing all the packages using npm install. The provided command was used :
`sudo rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`

Comment: Thank you! npm install then threw an error which told me which package was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That error happens because npm did change its package-lock.json format in version 7. So some of packages in your project were using old npm package-lock.json. Instead of deleting all packages and installing manually you could just

```
 npm update
```

This would update all the npm packages to its latest version

Answer (score 0):

I run into this error too and solved the issue by running:
"npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it! "

```
$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install on my bash-windows terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an error because my colleague deleted the package-lock.json file and then npm i.
I solved it like this:

1. Copy the history file containing lockfileVersion@1 from GitLab to package-lock.json
2. Delete node_modules
3. npm i