# Permanent fix for lockfileVersion of npm-shrinkwrap to lockfileVersion@1, it automatically makes lockfileversion@2?

Tags: npm, dockerfile, node-modules, github-actions

I am getting this when I am trying to push my code into github actions or building dockerimage.

```
 shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
```

I tried to implement this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67249859/is-there-way-to-lower-the-lockfileversion-of-npm-shrinkwrap-to-lockfileversion1) it works but again after some commit I am getting the same error and I have to repeat the same procedure again and again.

Any fix for that?

Answer (score -1):

Look in your .gitignore if you have the lines :

**package-lock.json**

**node_modules/**

if not,then add them,

after that look in your Github repository and delete the package-lock.json file and the node_modules directory (if any)

Important Edit :

My bad, Kevin Martin is right the official documentation tell us to add it to the repository for CI/CD.

> This file is intended to be committed into source repositories, and
> serves various purposes:
>
> Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that
> teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to
> install exactly the same dependencies.
>
> Provide a facility for users to "time-travel" to previous states of
> node_modules without having to commit the directory itself.
>
> To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable
> source control diffs.
>
> And optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated
> metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.

But for my case (Azure Devops) i had a lot of trouble with it.

Comment: I read somewhere that package-lock.json is not recommended to be put in .gitignore.

Comment: Sure it's better to let it in, but when your work with CI/CD often you got troubles with it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the exact case I got when I am building a Docker Image. Is there any other option available apart from deleting package-lock.json?

Comment: Package-lock.json is auto generated on build, so you only need it for "simplicity" and "convenient".. if you didn't not use it in a special process, i think you can delete it with out any trouble. From my experiences, you got trouble also with it on Git multi user on same branch, personaly, i prefer recreate it each time to be sur to have the good version...

Comment: Suppose If I delete package-lock.json then it may happen that a different version of the library may get released in the future and during testing it may again cause conflicting issues. Recently I was using node-sass in React in which I encountered the same problem. In npx CRA the sass dependency that is used there was version 4 but recently sass released version 6. Due to this, I face conflict issues.

Comment: Also it is mentioned in a post that we shouldn't delete package-lock.json. [Do I commit the package-lock.json file created by npm 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5)

Comment: @Kevin Martin, i'm agree with that, but i suppose that this is for CI/CD, so all the dependencies are always re-download, re-install, the package-lock.json will not be very usefull in this context, i think. If a package version changed, your directives in the package.json should not allow to download a more recent version (except minor fix)